# Set different language overlay settings for specific records in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase

With these TypoScript settings you can set the global language handling:

```
config.sys_language_mode    = strict
config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
```

Now, I want some records (from my own extension) to behave different, I need `sys_language_mode=content_fallback` and `sys_language_overlay=0`.
Is there a possibility to set a different language handling for specific records or extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to config it inside a condition.

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_myext_pi1|showUid > 0]
    config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    config.sys_language_overlay = 0
[GLOBAL]
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#globalvar

Comment: This will change the settings again for the whole page.

Answer (score -1):

You can Try below `typoscript condition` for specific plugin of your custom extension.

```
[globalVar = TCEFORM.tt_content.layout = 1] // Here you can select specific layout
 config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback
 config.sys_language_overlay = 0
[global]
```

Also You need to select specific layout(`in content appearance Tab`) for this plugin.